# How to create mixins with builders?

Tags: typescript

How can I join the two classes above (SelectController, SelectedController) with the main class (FilterData)?

I thought of using Mixin, however my question is referenced over the following:

The two helper classes mentioned above would need some "ID's" of "HTMLS" elements, and these elements I'd use both in the class itself and in the main class. But I know that with Mixin I can not create constructors within the two classes, so how do I use this method that I need?

```
class SelectController {
    constructor(protected modalBody: string, protected listbox: string) {}

    //METHODS
}

class SelectedController {
    constructor(protected listbox: string) {}

    //METHODS
}

class FilterData implements SelectController, SelectedController {
    constructor() {}

    //METHODS
}
```

Comment: Do you require that the `FilterData` class has a constructor that takes no arguments?

Comment: The code above was just an example, so I could show what I wanted .. But the constructor of the main class would have rather parameters. These parameters would be the information of the other classes to use as super ()

Comment: You can take `modalBody` and `listbox` in the constructor of `FilterData`, store them in the instance and then the methods in `SelectController` and `SelectedController` can access them via `this`. Will that work for you?

Comment: I am trying to separate the classes so there is no "overload" of many functions and attributes, but I was reading that the mixins it will cause an overload according to what I have said, since it needs to repeat the methods and attributes again in the class being implemented.

So I'm initializing classes inside my main class constructor, do you think right?